# Вывод элемента класса в строку

Tags: python

Суть проблемы:

```
class Critter(object):
    name = ' '
    age = 0
    hungry = random.randrange(11)
    sad = random.randrange(11)
    health = random.randrange(11)
    farm = []

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Name is '+ str(self.name) + '\n hungry ' + str(self.hungry) + '\n age is '+ str(self.age) + '\n sad is '+ str(self.sad) +'\n health ' + str(self.health) +' farm '+ str(self.farm)
```

Есть локальная функция, которая создает экземпляр класса:

```
def createAnimal():
    #  Создать животное
    name = input('Input name pls ')
    global population
    val = 'animal '+ str(population)
    population += 1
    val = Critter()
    val.name = name
    val.farm.append(val)
    print('Congrat you have a new animal with name ', name, ' in your farm a ', len(val.farm), ' animals', end='')
    print(val.farm)
```

При её вызове получаем такой результат:

```
Congrat you have a new animal with name  Bob  in your farm a  1  animals[<__main__.Critter object at 0x10e18cd30>]
```

Как вывести имя с названием животного в данном списке?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что Вы выводите на печать список `val.farm`. При этом, для каждого элемента списка вызывается функция `__repr__`. Отличия можно заметить в следующем примере:

```
In [1]: class Foo:
   ...:     def __repr__(self):
   ...:         return 'repr'
   ...:     def __str__(self):
   ...:         return 'str'
   ...:     

In [2]: f = Foo()

In [3]: f
Out[3]: repr

In [4]: print(f)
str

In [5]: print([Foo()])
[repr]
```

Если Вы хотите вывести список всех животных, Вам лучше воспользоваться методом [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
In [6]: class Foo:
   ...:     def __init__(self, name):
   ...:         self.name = name
   ...:     def __str__(self):
   ...:         return self.name
   ...:     

In [7]: l = [Foo('A dog'), Foo('A cat')]

In [8]: l
Out[8]: [<__main__.Foo at 0x7fd69451c630>, <__main__.Foo at 0x7fd69451c668>]

In [9]: ', '.join(f.name for f in l)
Out[9]: 'A dog, A cat'
```